# Combining UNION ALL and ORDER BY in Firebird

Tags: sql, database, database-design, firebird

Using Firebird, I want to combine the results of two queries using UNION ALL, then sort the resulting output on a given column.

```
(select C1, C2, C3 from T1)
union all 
(select C1, C2, C3 from T2)
order by C3
```

The parentheses came from valid syntax for other databases, and are needed to make sure the arguments to UNION ALL (an operation that's defined to work on tables - i.e. an *unordered* set of records) don't try to be ordered individually. However I couldn't get this syntax to work in Firebird--how can it be done?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
SELECT C1, C2, C3
FROM (
    select C1, C2, C3 from T1
    union all 
    select C1, C2, C3 from T2
)
order by C3
```

Comment: Note that this query requires Firebird 2.x or higher

Answer (score 13):

Field names are not required to be equal. That's why you can't use the field name in the order by.
You may use the field index instead. As in:

```
(select C1, C2, C3 from T1)
union all 
(select C7, C8, C9 from T2)
order by 3
```

Comment: As written this requires Firebird 2.x, but if you remove the parentheses this will also work in Firebird 1.5

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
select C1, C2, C3 from T1
union all 
select C1, C2, C3 from T2
order by 2
```

At least in the newer Firebird Versions it works if you order by "Number" instead of using an Alias.

Answer (score 2):

In Firebird 1.5 this works for me

```
create view V1 (C1, C2, C3) as
  select C1, C2, C3 from T1
  union all 
  select C1, C2, C3 from T2
```

and then

```
select C1, C2, C3 from V1 order by C3
```

Comment: +1 for "backwards" compatibility, the other answers doesn't work in Firebird 1.5

Comment: @Chris This is the same answer as Chris' one. You should delete yours or improve Chris' answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perform the UNION ALL in a view (without the ORDER BY clause), then select from the view using ORDER BY.

Comment: +1 for "backwards" compatibility, the other answers doesn't work in Firebird 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Moving `order by` into a query tail has **no** effect to output datagrid.

```
select * from (
    select first 1
        C1
    from T1
    order by id desc
)
union all
select * from (
    select first 1
        C1
    from T2
    order by id desc
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more verbose and complicated than other solutions, but perhaps you still find this useful. You can use `NATURAL FULL JOIN` with a distinct discriminator between its operands to produce `UNION ALL` behaviour. With that, you can continue ordering by column names, or other expressions:

```sql
select c1, c2, c3 
from (select 't1' as x, t1.* from t1) as t1
natural full join (select 't2' as x, t2.* from t2) as t2
order by c3
```