# Select with count by item and total count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am using the following procedure to add a count per item which works fine so far.

How do I have to change this if I also want to get the total count in addition so that it counts all items in that select ?

**My procedure:**

```
SELECT      RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc, policy) [Rank],
            policy, 
            COUNT(*) AS groupCount,
            'currentMonth' AS groupName
FROM        Log_PE 
WHERE       CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112) + '01', 112)
GROUP BY    policy
ORDER BY    groupCount desc, policy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered in another post :
[SUM of grouped COUNT in SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927268/sum-of-grouped-count-in-sql-query)

```
select name, COUNT(name) as count from Table
group by name
    Union all
select 'SUM', COUNT(name)
from Table
```

Comment: Thanks. I already have a Group By for my count per item. How can I use your suggestion in this case ?

Comment: I just tested it, it does not pose any problem. Just put the 'union all' after the 'group by' clause

Comment: just the order by is tricky : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354224/combining-union-all-and-order-by-in-firebird

Answer (score 0):

Take a llok at **[GROUP BY Modifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)**.

The part that might be helpful is **WITH ROLLUP**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use With Rollup(As suggested by blue ) as well as Grouping Sets,
Grouping sets give you more flexibility-

```
SELECT      RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc, policy) [Rank],
            policy, 
            COUNT(*) AS groupCount,
            'currentMonth' AS groupName
FROM        Log_PE 
WHERE       CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112) + '01', 112)
GROUP BY Grouping Sets (policy,())
ORDER BY    groupCount desc, policy
```