# Simple sql Query to find manager and employee details

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I have created a query to find employee details and supervisor details of an organization now i want that every employees name should be repeated in the supervisor column also once.
Means :

```
  employee num Supervisor num 

     1            2 
   **1            1**
     2            3
   **2            2** 
     3            4
   etc
```

The query i wrote to get employee number and supervisor num is :-

```
 Select a.employee_num,a.supervisor_num
 from managers a;
```

This query will just give me....

```
 employee num Supervisor num 

     1            2 
     2            3
     3            4
```

Any suggestion will be helpful :)

Comment: plz add some more details as it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Your question as it is makes no sense. Please give more details on it.

Comment: Hi.. @AnkitBajpai  I have added that i require normal employee number and supervisor number and then the employer number also repeat itself

Comment: Now I understood what you want. But even so I would like to know why you need this?! What would be your requirement to make you do this? Just curious.

Comment: @JorgeCampos- Its a client requirement.. they need it for some hierchy breakup :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
(SELECT a.employee_num,
        a.supervisor_num
 FROM managers a)
UNION ALL
(SELECT DISTINCT a.employee_num,
        a.employee_num AS supervisor_num
 FROM managers a)
ORDER BY 1,2
```

The first query is just like the one you created. The second will add every employee as a manager. Ordering the whole union will create the resultset you want.

Comment: +1 for exposing me to order by field index.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354224/combining-union-all-and-order-by-in-firebird